# How to cleanup binary that has been converted to string without decoding?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8

Is there a clean way of bringing wrongly converted binary string back to binary to decode it? I have these headers in a csv file that are like below:

```
import pandas as pd 
tsv_file="C:\\Users\ruser\Downloads\\mydata.tsv"
tsv_table=pd.read_table(tsv_file,sep='\t')
print(tsv_table.columns)
>>> Index(['b'time (s)'', 'b'Red (mN)'', 'b'Blue (mN)'', 'b'Green (mN)'',
       'b'Pink (mN)''],
      dtype='object')
```

I'd love a clean way to process this without string processing. Is there a way?

**Edit:**
I would love to just use

```
tsv_table.colums.str.decode('utf-8')
```

But it isn't in utf-8 format right? It's a string. We just end up with Nan's

```
print(csv_table.columns.str.decode('utf-8'))
Float64Index([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')
```

Edit 2:

`mydata.tsv`

```
b'time (s)' b'Red (mN)' b'Blue (mN)'    b'Green (mN)'   b'Pink (mN)'

0.0 28.0393760805021    29.350510817307736  0.5422318347392547  1.1041605247641542

0.010000008061766026    1.1736308159200206  29.327035757211547  0.5235093941717537  1.1041605247641542

0.02000001612353205 1.1736308159200206  29.373985877403868  0.5422318347392547  1.1425474154873996
```

Comment: Given any string, x, the bytes of that string are x.encode(). Likewise, given any sequence of bytes, y, the python string is y.decode(). Is that what you want?

Comment: is your column names enclosed within single quotes ?

Comment: @Naveen I believe so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by converting the Python-syntax string into an actual byte string, then decodes it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast

table = pd.read_table('mydata.tsv',sep='\t')
table.columns = [ast.literal_eval(x).decode('utf8') for x in table.columns]
print(table)
```

```
   time (s)   Red (mN)  Blue (mN)  Green (mN)  Pink (mN)
0      0.00  28.039376  29.350511    0.542232   1.104161
1      0.01   1.173631  29.327036    0.523509   1.104161
2      0.02   1.173631  29.373986    0.542232   1.142547
```

Comment: Awesome answer! Didn't know about literal evaluation until this